# Understanding the parameters of translating the pesukim

Tags: translation, targumin, maseches-kiddushin

In [Kiddushin 49a](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.49a.11?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) R' Yehuda makes the following statement

> ר' יהודה אומר המתרגם פסוק כצורתו הרי זה בדאי והמוסיף עליו הרי זה מחרף ומגדף
>
> One who translates a verse literally is a liar, one who adds his own translation is [tantamount to] one who curses and blasphemes God

Rashi there essentially explains that any translation that deviates by adding or subtracting from the accepted 'Onkelos' translation is what R' Yehuda is referring to (see Tosfot there). I would like to understand the parameters of this idea.

1. (How) would this apply to other traditional *targumim* such as pseudo-Yonatan, Yerushalmi or [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Targum#Other_Targumim_on_the_Torah)?
2. Would this apply to translations of the Torah into languages other than Aramaic?
3. Would this apply to the rest of Tanach or only the Pentateuch (see Megillah 3a)?

Comment: Rashi's comments indicate that Rabbi Y'huda was talking specifically about Unk'lus's Aramaic translation, as it was received not manufactured, so taking any creative license with it is a deviation. Were the other translations used as part of public Torah reading?

Comment: RELATED: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91716/if-the-targum-on-the-torah-written-by-onkelus-was-given-at-har-sinai-how-can-ra